# Calling Methods and Functions

Tags: jsf-2

in jsf2 if we have some function like

```
public String greeting(String gtr) {
        return "Hello " + gtr;
}
```

then from jsf page we can call this function as

```
<h:outputLabel value="#{greetingBean.greeting['some-name']}"
```

now my question is i want to pass the dynamic parameter from the same bean class instead of 'some-name' something like `value="#{greetingBean.greeting[greetingBean.name]}` is it possible ?

i required this because i have value in `Map<String, ArrayList>` and want to edit particular ArrayList value ?

any suggestions ?

Comment: i tried it and gives error so wondering if any workaround for this

Comment: What version of EL are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brackets are used to replace the dot notation. That is,

```
#{greetingBean.greeting['some-name']}
```

is the same as

```
#{greetingBean.greeting.some-name}
```

So, the `greeting` method will not be called. Instead, JSF will try to access a `greeting` property, and then try to access a `some-name` property of the object returned by `greeting` property. That is, your code above is already generating an error.

If you are using EL 2.2 and want to call an action, simply put:

```
#{greetingBean.greeting('some-name')}
```

or

```
#{greetingBean.greetingThatReceivesAMap(greetingBean.name)}
```